# How do you overlap variables?

Tags: javascript, audio

I am creating a Launchpad in which an audio file starts/stops when a button is clicked. I have this working, but when I try and add multiple audio files, they refuse to overlap each other correctly. The 2nd audio file will not play when the 1st audio file is playing. Is there a way to get this working? Below is an example of 2 buttons, with 2 separate audio files linked to them. I want to overlap these audio files so that when the project is complete (64 audio files/buttons), users can piece together multiple audio files to create their own unique tracks.

```js
var one = new Audio();
one.src = "files/audio/one.wav";
one.loop = true;

var two = new Audio();
two.src = "files/audio/two.wav";
two.loop = true;

var isPlaying = false;

function manage1() {
  if (isPlaying) {
    one.pause();
    isPlaying = false;
    one.currentTime = 0;
  } else {
    one.play();
    isPlaying = true;
    one.currentTime = 0;
  }
}

function manage2() {
  if (isPlaying) {
    two.pause();
    isPlaying = false;
    two.currentTime = 0;
  } else {
    two.play();
    isPlaying = true;
    two.currentTime = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="item" src="files/button.png" onclick="manage1();" />
<img class="item" src="files/button.png" onclick="manage2();" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use two different variables for your play/pause tracker.

Here, `isPlaying` tracks your first audio and `isSecondPlaying` tracks your second audio.

```
var one = new Audio(); one.src = "files/audio/one.wav"; one.loop = true;

var two = new Audio(); two.src = "files/audio/two.wav"; two.loop = true;

var isPlaying = false;
var isSecondPlaying = false;

function manage1(){
  if(isPlaying){
    one.pause();
    isPlaying = false;
        one.currentTime = 0;
  }
  else{
    one.play();
    isPlaying = true;
        one.currentTime = 0;
  }
}

function manage2(){
  if(isSecondPlaying ){
    two.pause();
    isSecondPlaying = false;
        two.currentTime = 0;
  }
  else{
    two.play();
    isSecondPlaying = true;
        two.currentTime = 0;
  }
}
```

**BUT**:

If you want to do this for 64 audio files, you might want to rethink your method :

```js
var audio = [];
var isPlaying = [];

function manage(id) {
  if (isPlaying[id]) {
    audio[id].pause();
    isPlaying[id] = false;
    audio[id].currentTime = 0;
  } else {
    audio[id].play();
    isPlaying[id] = true;
    audio[id].currentTime = 0;
  }
}

function createAudio(src, i) {
  audio[i] = new Audio();
  audio[i].src = src;
  audio[i].loop = true;
  isPlaying[i] = false;
}

var mySources = ['path/to/1.wav', 'path/to/2.wav', 'path/to/3.wav', 'path/to/4.wav', 'path/to/5.wav'];

for (var i = 1; i <= mySources.length; i++) {
  createAudio(mySources[i - 1], i);
}
```

```html
<img class="item" src="files/button.png" onclick="manage(1);" />
<img class="item" src="files/button.png" onclick="manage(2);" />
<img class="item" src="files/button.png" onclick="manage(3);" />
<img class="item" src="files/button.png" onclick="manage(4);" />
<img class="item" src="files/button.png" onclick="manage(5);" />
```

To initialize you audios, just call `createAudio('yourAudio.wav',1);`
And change the source & ID.

Comment: That works! You've been great help dude. I can't quite get my head around the alternative method for using 64 audio files, I'm not understanding the `[id]` and `[i]` with me being new to JS. If you could update your answer with an example of using 2 or 3 audio files i'm sure i'd be able to work it out from there. If not, then thank you anyway, you've been great help.

Comment: I edited my answer with the full solution to this. Let me explain it a bit : All you have to do is put all your sources inside the `mySources` array. The function `createAudio()` will be called exaclty the number of time needed thanks to the `for` loop. If you don't know it already, you should read about Arrays in Javascript. They are a way to store multiple informations inside the same variable. To access different informations, you give the variable an index to search, for example : `myArray(2)`. It will return the 3rd element from `myArray`.

Comment: Okay that helped me get my head around it, and it works great! For some reason though, the last one (5) doesn't work? Chrome console gives me the error: _Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources.
manage @ index.html:28
onclick @ index.html:74_ Any ideas?

Comment: Can you put your code in a JSFiddle so I can test it?

Comment: I can't find a site to upload my local files on to, so I've uploaded everything to GitHub if that helps? (https://github.com/WilsonNCN/Launch3D) // Or let me know of a site to upload my local files to and i'll do that, whichever suits you.

Comment: The working site is here (https://wilsonncn.github.io/Launch3D/) and as you can see, the bottom button on the first column doesn't play any audio (I'm only working on the first column so far).

Comment: Figured out what seems to be happening is that it's ignoring the first audio file (one.wav) then starting with (two.wav) on the first button, leaving the eighth button blank.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to add a `-1`, my bad ! I edited the answer.

Comment: Genius! Thanks a bunch, you've been great help!

Comment: I don't suppose you'd know how to create a stop button for each row? I've made a question about it but no response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616153/button-stops-multiple-audio-tracks

Comment: I'll take a look and post an answer on your new question :)