# Button stops multiple audio tracks

Tags: javascript, html, function, audio, onclick

I am creating a Launchpad, and each row is built of 8 buttons/audio tracks and a stop button. I am wanting each stop button to stop all audio playing on that row when pressed, e.g. Stop Button 1 will stop sound(1) to sound(8). Any ideas? I will leave my code below (Ignore the offImg/onImg that's for the images):

JS:

```
var audio = [];
var isPlaying = [];

function sound(id){
  if(isPlaying[id]){
    audio[id].pause();
    isPlaying[id] = false;
    audio[id].currentTime = 0;
  }
  else{
    audio[id].play();
    isPlaying[id] = true;
    audio[id].currentTime = 0;
  }
}

function createAudio(src,i){
  audio[i] = new Audio();
  audio[i].src = src;
  audio[i].loop = true;
  isPlaying[i] = false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img class="top" src="images/pink.png" onclick="sound(1); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offD1)? onImgPnk : offD1);"/>
<img class="top" src="images/pink.png" onclick="sound(2); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offD2)? onImgPnk : offD2);"/>
<img class="top" src="images/pink.png" onclick="sound(3); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offD3)? onImgPnk : offD3);"/>
<img class="top" src="images/pink.png" onclick="sound(4); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offD4)? onImgPnk : offD4);"/>
<img class="top" src="images/pink.png" onclick="sound(5); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offD5)? onImgPnk : offD5);"/>
<img class="top" src="images/pink.png" onclick="sound(6); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offD6)? onImgPnk : offD6);"/>
<img class="top" src="images/pink.png" onclick="sound(7); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offD7)? onImgPnk : offD7);"/>
<img class="top" src="images/pink.png" onclick="sound(8); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offD8)? onImgPnk : offD8);"/>
<img class="muteTop" src="images/mute.png" onclick="this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImg)? onImgMut : offImg);"/>
<div class="top"></div> ***** <--- THIS IS THE STOP BUTTON *****
```

**EDIT**

```
var stopButton = document.getElementById(stop1); 

stopButton.addEventListener('click', stopAllAudio);

function stopAllAudio(){
      var audios = document.getElementsByClassName("top"),
          len = audios.length,
          i = 0;
      for (; i < len; i++){
          audios[i].currentTime = 0;
          audios[i].pause();
          isPlaying[i] = false;
      }
}
```

HTML:

```
<img class="top" src="images/pink.png" onclick="sound(1); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offD1)? onImgPnk : offD1);"/>
<img class="top" src="images/pink.png" onclick="sound(2); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offD2)? onImgPnk : offD2);"/>
<img class="top" src="images/pink.png" onclick="sound(3); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offD3)? onImgPnk : offD3);"/>
<img class="top" src="images/pink.png" onclick="sound(4); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offD4)? onImgPnk : offD4);"/>
<img class="top" src="images/pink.png" onclick="sound(5); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offD5)? onImgPnk : offD5);"/>
<img class="top" src="images/pink.png" onclick="sound(6); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offD6)? onImgPnk : offD6);"/>
<img class="top" src="images/pink.png" onclick="sound(7); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offD7)? onImgPnk : offD7);"/>
<img class="top" src="images/pink.png" onclick="sound(8); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offD8)? onImgPnk : offD8);"/>
<img class="muteTop" src="images/mute.png" onclick="this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImg)? onImgMut : offImg);"/>
<div class="top" id="stop1"></div> ***** <--- THIS IS THE STOP BUTTON *****
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this gives you some idea.

```
var stopButton = ...; // select your stop button

stopButton.addEventListener('click', stopAllAudio);

function stopAllAudio(){
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio'),
        len = audios.length,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
        audios[i].currentTime = 0;
        audios[i].pause();
        isPlaying[i] = false;
    }
}
```

You can select element(s) using the following ways:

1. [Select by Id](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)
2. [Select by ClassName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)
3. [Select by TagName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp)

You can trigger functions on certain element(s) using [addEventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp).

You can loop through selected element(s) using [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).

Comment: Thanks, this seems helpful. I'm new to JS tho, any idea how i'd implement it?

Comment: updated. Do your stop button has an id? if yes, `var stopButton = document.getElementById(/* stop button's id */);`

Comment: How would I add an id to the stop button?

Comment: @NathanWilson add it through HTML `<div class="top" id="stopButton"></div>` is the easiest way.

Comment: Ok I feel asthough I understand now, but after implementing the code it isn't allowing me to click any buttons. I have edited the code in my question for you to take another look.

Comment: @NathanWilson that's probably because there is an error in your code. Inspect element to view error. From what I see, the error is in `audio = document.getElementsByClassName('top')` and `audios[i].pause()`. One of your `<div>` has className of `top` and `<div>` do not have `div.pause()` function. So error occurred and stopped further execution of your code.

Comment: @NathanWilson also, is your `<audio>` element has `class="top"`? If not, you cannot use `audio = document.getElementsByClassName('top')` because you are not going to select any `<audio>` to be paused.

Comment: Inspecting element gives me these 2 errors: `index.html:47 Uncaught ReferenceError: stop1 is not defined at index.html:47` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined at sound (index.html:41) at HTMLImageElement.onclick (index.html:99)` // I don't know if that's any help to you. If so, if you could edit it into your answer it would be so much help, this is for a college project and i'm struggling rn! (The stop button kinda needs to be a class and not an id because id positions it differently for some reason).

Comment: @NathanWilson your first error: `document.getElementById(stop1)`. The "stop1" should be closed between quotes (you should notice from my answer). Your second error, you are attaching audio events onto image elements. You should read up more about javascript in [w3schools](www.w3schools.com) as a web development beginner. StackOverflow does not help and teach you to write code but rather help you through coding bottleneck. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If all your rows are well defined, you could do something like this :

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <img class="top" src="images/pink.png" onclick="sound(1); this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offD1)? onImgPnk : offD1);"/>
    [...]
    <div class="stop"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click','.stop',function(){
    $(this).siblings('img.top').each(function(){
        audio[$(this).index()+1].pause();
        audio[$(this).index()+1].currentTime = 0;
        isPlaying[$(this).index()+1] = false;
    });
});
```

Basicly, you listen to the click on your `.stop` div.

When one is clicked, you search for all the other `img.top` elements in the same parent, and then `.pause()` them one by one.

I used JQuery here because it's way easier & faster.
But if you want a pure javascript solution, just tell me.